# Extracting last date of the year from a date object

Tags: r

I have following data set:

```
>d
x     date
1 1 1-3-2013
2 2 2-4-2010
3 3 2-5-2011
4 4 1-6-2012
```

I want:

```
> d
x       date
1 1 31-12-2013
2 2 31-12-2010
3 3 31-12-2011
4 4 31-12-2012
```

i.e. Last day, last month and the year of the date object.

Please Help!

Answer (score 5):

You can also just use the **ceiling_date** function in LUBRIDATE package.

You can do something like -

```
library(lubridate)
last_date <- ceiling_date(date,"year") - days(1)
```

**ceiling_date(date,"year")** gives you the first date of the next year and to get the last date of the current year, you subtract this by 1 or days(1).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `lubridate` package:

```
## using d from Roland answer
transform(d,last =dmy(paste0('3112',year(dmy(date)))))
 x     date       last
1 1 1-3-2013 2013-12-31
2 2 2-4-2010 2010-12-31
3 3 2-5-2011 2011-12-31
4 4 1-6-2012 2012-12-31
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d <- read.table(text="x     date
1 1 1-3-2013
2 2 2-4-2010
3 3 2-5-2011
4 4 1-6-2012", header=TRUE)

d$date <- as.Date(d$date, "%d-%m-%Y")
d$date <- as.POSIXlt(d$date)
d$date$mon <- 11
d$date$mday <- 31

d$date <- as.Date(d$date)

#  x       date
#1 1 2013-12-31
#2 2 2010-12-31
#3 3 2011-12-31
#4 4 2012-12-31
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) cut.Date** Define `cut_year` to give the first day of the year.  Adding 366 gets us to the next year and then applying `cut_year` again gets us to the first day of the next year.  Finally subtract 1 to get the last day of the year.  The code uses base functionality only.

```
cut_year <- function(x) as.Date(cut(as.Date(x), "year"))
transform(d, date = cut_year(cut_year(date) + 366) - 1)
```

**2) format**

```
transform(d, date = as.Date(format(as.Date(date), "%Y-12-31")))
```

**3) zoo**  A `"yearmon"` class variable stores the date as a year plus 0 for Jan, 1/12 for Feb, ..., 11/12 for Dec.  Thus taking its floor and adding 11/12 gets one to Dec and `as.Date.yearmon(..., frac = 1)` uses the last of the month instead of the first.

```
library(zoo)
transform(d, date = as.Date(floor(as.yearmon(as.Date(date))) + 11 / 12, frac = 1))
```

*Note*: The inner `as.Date` in `cut_year` and in the other two solutions can be omitted if it is known that `date` is already of `"Date"` class.

ADDED additional solutions.